# Pyspark 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: attributes, pyspark

I
I want to  find out what all the items in df which are not in df1 , also items in df1 but not in df

```
    df =sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4 ,5 ,6,7,8,9])
    df1=sc.parallelize([4 ,5 ,6,7,8,9,10])
    df2 = df.subtract(df1)
    df2.show()
    df3 = df1.subtract(df)
    df3.show()
```

Just want to check the result to see if I understand the function well.
But got this error
        'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'show'
any suggestion?

Answer (score 23):

```
print(df2.take(10))
```

`df.show()` is only for spark DataFrame

Comment: How to convert to spark dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Convert an rdd to a spark dataframe with [createDataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame)