# AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, sql
from pyspark.sql import Row
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)
df = sc.parallelize([ \
                 Row(nama='Roni', umur=27, tingi=168), \
                 Row(nama='Roni', umur=6, tingi=168),
                 Row(nama='Roni', umur=89, tingi=168),])

df.show()
```

> error:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "ipython-input-24-bfb18ebba99e", line 8, in  df.show()
>
> AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'show'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154721/pyspark-pipelinedrdd-object-has-no-attribute-show) and also related to [Spark RDD to DataFrame python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699107/spark-rdd-to-dataframe-python)

Answer (score 9):

The error is clear as `df` is an rdd. You should change it to a dataframe using `toDF` likes in the following code:

```
df = df.toDF()
df.show()
```